# Fastlane passed parameters from CLI are trimmed

Tags: github-actions, fastlane

I am trying to pass the Pull request title as a parameter to the lane

I run this command for example
`fastlane android distribute release_notes:$PR_TITLE`
And I can see from the logs that the command is executed correctly with the complete title
`[16:37:52]: $ bundle exec fastlane android distribute release_notes:ref: copy the services module inside app module`

but when I print the passed argument I found it trimmed

```
    desc "distribute new build for testers, set internal to true to pass it for internal testrs"
    lane :distribute do |options|
        print "\n"
        print "release_notes"

        print options[:release_notes]
```

which prints `release_notes ref:`, trimmed after the `:` and it even gets trimmed after newlines  in a strange way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your `release_notes:string` command, fastlane parses colons in a key/value format. So it will break if you pass in a string which includes a colon.

A more common pattern is to read the release notes from the environment variable within your lane. So instead of using `options` at all just do something like

```
notes = ENV['PR_TITLE']
```